# Calling data from 2 table & counting them

Tags: mysql

I have 2 tables containing different data. Let me explain you both the table.

Table - A
id, val

Table -B
id, product

id is the common column between these two.

I want to find the 'id' having a type of 'val' from Table A. I did that.
I want to find the 'product' of those 'id' from Table B. How do I do that? & I want to find the total number of each products (like what we do using count).

Can anybody please help?

Comment: Show us db schema, sample data and expected output. 
 Please read [**How-to-Ask**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)
 
 And here is a great place to [**START**](http://spaghettidba.com/2015/04/24/how-to-post-a-t-sql-question-on-a-public-forum/) to learn how improve your question quality and get better answers.

 [**How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Answer (score 1):

Hope help you

```
SELECT a.val, b.product COUNT(*) AS numrow 
FROM A AS a 
LEFT JOIN B AS b ON a.id = b.id 
WHERE a.val =something_to_find
```

Comment: To format as `code`, select the text and press `ctrl-k`  or add 4 spaces before each line